# Does the output of a Docker image depends on the Host OS?

Tags: docker

I am completely new to Docker and only know that a Docker image wraps up everything (code, dependencies etc, etc) and then, you can run that Docker image as a container on any host system (containing a Docker engine). Among other things, this makes sure that for the same input, you will get the same output.

Keeping the moto "***same input -> same output***" logic in mind, I am using a [**pRF-validation framework**](https://github.com/vistalab/PRFmodel/wiki). The following docker images are required to be pulled:

```
prf-Synthesize: docker pull garikoitz/prfsynth
prf-Analyze-vista: docker pull garikoitz/prfanalyze-vista
prf-Report: docker pull garikoitz/prfreport
```

I tried running the above docker containers on **Windows-11, Mac OS and Ubuntu**. The containers ran successfully and the container `prfreport` creates a PNG image as a result.

**PROBLEM:** On a given OS, if I run the containers multiple times then I get the same output results. ***However, the generated results are different to each other on all three OS, and are also quite different from the expected result image posted on the framework's Wiki.***

Does this mean that the output of a Docker container may depend on the Host OS?

**MWE:** To reproduce the issue, you need to pull the docker images (mentioned above) and then execute the following commands. There is also step-by-step description on their [Github Wiki](https://github.com/vistalab/PRFmodel/wiki).

```
prfsynth
----------
docker run --rm -it -v empty:/flywheel/v0/input/config.json -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/output garikoitz/prfsynth
rename D:\results\docker-analysis\02-test\prfsynth-config-defaults.json prfsynth_sub-001_sess-20200320.json

Edit the generated JSON file
{
    "subjectName": "001",
    "sessionName": "20200320",
    // other parameters...
}
docker run --rm -it -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test/prfsynth_sub-001_sess-20200320.json:/flywheel/v0/input/config.json -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/output garikoitz/prfsynth


prf-Analyze
----------
docker run --rm -it -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test/empty:/flywheel/v0/input:ro -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/output garikoitz/prfanalyze-vista:latest
rename D:\results\docker-analysis\02-test\prfanalyze-vista-default-config.json prfanalyze-vista-config_sub-001_sess-20200320.json

Edit the generated JSON file
{
    "subjectName": "001",
    "sessionName": "20200320",
    // other parameters...
}

docker run --rm -it -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/input -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/output -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test/prfanalyze-vista-config_sub-001_sess-20200320.json:/flywheel/v0/input/config.json:ro garikoitz/prfanalyze-vista


prf-Report
------------
docker run --rm -it -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test/empty:/flywheel/v0/input/config.json -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/output garikoitz/prfreport
move "D:\results\docker-analysis\02-test\prfreport-configuration-defaults.json" "D:\results\docker-analysis/02-test\prfreport-config_sub-001_sess-20200320.json"

Edit the generated JSON file
{
    "subjectName": "001",
    "sessionName": "20200320",
    // other parameters...
}

docker run --rm -it -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test/prfreport-config_sub-001_sess-20200320.json:/flywheel/v0/input/config.json -v D:/results/docker-analysis/02-test:/flywheel/v0/output garikoitz/prfreport
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: @BMitch: Added MWE. There is no additional data needed. Anybody can reproduce the issue. Also the step-by-step guide on their Wiki: https://github.com/vistalab/PRFmodel/wiki